# I have a fatal exception while using playtika test containers for google pubsub

Tags: java, segmentation-fault, integration-testing, google-cloud-pubsub, testcontainers

I am having a fatal exception while trying to build an integration test on Jenkins although it works fine on local Intellij on Mac OS :

```
[DEBUG] # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
[DEBUG] #
[DEBUG] #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000003fd6, pid=95, tid=0x00007f73d8feeb10
[DEBUG] #
[DEBUG] # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b04) (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
[DEBUG] # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
[DEBUG] # Derivative: IcedTea 3.12.0
[DEBUG] # Distribution: Custom build (Sat May  4 17:33:35 UTC 2019)
[DEBUG] # Problematic frame:
[DEBUG] # C  0x0000000000003fd6
[DEBUG] #
[DEBUG] # Core dump written. Default location: /home/jenkins/workspace/le-service_feature_DI-13019/core or core.95
[DEBUG] #
[DEBUG] # An error report file with more information is saved as:
[DEBUG] # /home/jenkins/workspace/le-service_feature_DI-13019/hs_err_pid95.log
[DEBUG] #
[DEBUG] # If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
[DEBUG] # instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
[DEBUG] #   https://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
[DEBUG] #
```

I cant see the logs on Jenkins in the provided path

The moment the container is created and up I have this fatal exception

another part of the log

```
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/workspace/le-service_feature_DI-13019 && /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java -javaagent:/root/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.8/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.8-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/jenkins/workspace/le-service_feature_DI-13019/target/jacoco.exec,append=true -jar /home/jenkins/workspace/le-service_feature_DI-13019/target/surefire/surefirebooter602603825469423467.jar /home/jenkins/workspace/le-service_feature_DI-13019/target/surefire 2022-09-08T16-46-13_263-jvmRun1 surefire6688438040654119002tmp surefire_07067221753418690335tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 134
```

Comment: This is a low-level JVM error in the used JRE installed on Jenkins. Please make sure you are using the same JDK versions and variants across your environments.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I actually figured that out and was too busy to update the question.
yes my local JDK8 is more upgraded than the image we use on Jenkins and simply upgrading the JDK to latest 8 version on Jenkins base image solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my case What Kevin Wittek pointed out was the problem.
simply my local JDK was more updated than the Jenkins one which had a low level bug.

I tried a branch with
adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine-slim (8u292-b10)
instead of
openjdk:8-jdk-alpine (java 8 8u111)which is deprecated and it works.